# Subscript for column names in R and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, markdown

As title, how do you include subscript/superscript for table to be rendered in Shiny?
There seems to be solution for [rownames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537398/render-sub-superscript-in-table-shiny) but no question on the column names.

One way is to directly change the column names of dataframe using unicode, such as:

```
test <- data.frame(
  "\u03C3\u2080" = integer(),
  "\u03C3\u2122" = integer(),
  "\u03b1\u209b\u1d64\u209a" = integer()
)
colnames(test) = c("\u03C3\u2080", "\u03C3\u2122", "\u03b1\u209b\u1d64\u209a")
test
```

it leaves a lot to be desired as you cannot directly assign some unicode to columnname (redundantly have to use `colnames()`), and cannot use characters that unicode does not support, because [unicode hates alphabet letter `q` for some reason.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638471/why-does-the-unicode-superscripts-and-subscripts-block-not-contain-simple-sequen)

When user is just trying to export dataframe as word doc or something, user can use external package such as `kable()` to use markdown and display subscript/superscript, but how does one do that in Shiny environment?

```
output$test <- renderTable({
   test <- data.frame(
      "sigma_zero" = integer(),
      "sigma^tm" = integer(),
      "alpha_sup" = integer()
    )
  #colnames(test) = c("\u03C3\u2080", "\u03C3\u2122", "\u03b1\u209b\u1d64\u209a")
  return(test)
})
```

Comment: Try the datatable function as part of the DT package.

Comment: I wanted to use `renderTable()`, but I did look up `renderDT()` for future use, and the solution for that family of rendering was `escape = FALSE` argument, while using HTML as Stephanie answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    test <- data.frame(
      "sigma_zero" = integer(),
      "sigma^tm" = integer(),
      "alpha_sup" = integer()
    )
    colnames(test) = 
      c("&sigma;<sub>0</sub>", "&sigma;<sup>TM</sup>", "&alpha;<sub>sup</sub>")
    return(test)
  }, sanitize.colnames.function = identity)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]